# Pros and cons of using subdomain to identify customers

Tags: business-logic, subdomain

I see websites like Wufoo that give every new customer a way to [register their own subdomain](https://secure.wufoo.com/signup/1/) on their site (ex https://mystuff.wufoo.com) What are the benefits of doing this? I'm specifically curious about technical pros and cons of this approach.

Why not do https://wufoo.com/mystuff ? Is it just aesthetics?

Comment: Can't speak for technical (besides needing a wildcard SSL certificate) but whenever a site gives me my own subdomain it seems like I matter more.

Comment: http://www.webmasterworld.com/webmaster/3483209.htm?highlight=msg3483273

Answer (score 0):

An obvious drawback that I should have spotted.  If you do `https://hostname.com/mystuff` that means that `mystuff` cannot be used for internal use.  This is going to be causing issues with your page names like `https://hostname.com/pricing` <- `pricing` is taken and users will not be able to register this name...So it is inconvenient to both users and developers.